# Conditionally expect a string or object type for React prop with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, prop

I am using React and Typescript.

In one component the prop `myDate` expect a `string` but in another component it expect an `object`.

I have the following component:

```
const MyBlock = ({ data: myType }: Props) => {
  const { data } = useQuery<GqlRes>(MyQuery, {
    variables: {
      type: myType,
    },
    errorPolicy: 'all',
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    ssr: false,
  });

  const items =
    data?.items?.map((node) => {
      return {
        id: node.id,
        type: TeaserType.Video,
        title: node.title,
        myDate: node.myDateTime,
      };
    }) || [];

  return data?.items?.length ? (
    <Carousel items={items} />
  ) : null;
};

export default MyBlock;
```

In **this** component the `myDate` prop `node.myDateTime` is a string.

But in another component

In the child component `<Carousel />` the props are typed like:

```
interface DateValue {
  timestamp: number;
  formatted: string;
}

export type Props = {
  items: {
    id: string;
    myDate?: DateValue;
  }[];
};
```

And passed like:

```
tag: node?.myDate?.timestamp
```

How do I solve this? I tried the following:

For the `<Carousel />` types:

```
export type Props = {
  items: {
    id: string;
    myDate?: DateValue | string;
  }[];
};
```

But then I get the following Typescript message:

```
Property 'timestamp' does not exist on type 'string | DateValue'.
  Property 'timestamp' does not exist on type 'string'
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
Property 'timestamp' does not exist on type 'string | DateValue'.
  Property 'timestamp' does not exist on type 'string'
```

What this error is saying is that you can't access the `timestamp` property of `'string | DateValue'` because you can't access the `timestamp` property of `string` because `string` doesn't have it.

If I could simplify your example to produce this error, it might look like this:

```
interface DateValue {
  timestamp: number;
  formatted: string;
}

type Props = {
  items: {
    id: string;
    myDate: DateValue | string;
  }[];
};

declare const props: Props // tell the type system we have some Props
const timestamp = props.items[0].myDate.timestamp // your error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-beta#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJ0gNTgGwK4oDeAUMsmMALYQDOYclADgFzIh6UBG0A3KcjAD2UShkgATVnSigA5nwC+xYmACejFAAUogxjWQBeZCTLBIlGqxNlkwScmly+N5JVXpIrDxGz4UAHwcwGRB5fgUAbQBdRT5icQgEHDgoFARBEDpkRh09Vm1dfQB6IvIIHBxyAAsUNQ0HVToISmQAdxQquAA3FBpBamQCvWJ0zLByKlp6JkNs3JoAOjNmmgiABiiFt28Fimo6BkZkEuRVQTwoZGgdKCA)

To fix it, you have to check the type *before* you treat it like an object.

For example:

```
const myDate = props.items[0].myDate // string | DateValue
const timestamp = typeof myDate === 'string' ? myDate : myDate.timestamp // string | number
// then do something with `timestamp` here.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJ0gNTgGwK4oDeAUMsmMALYQDOYclADgFzIh6UBG0A3KcjAD2UShkgATVnSigA5nwC+xYmACejFAAUogxjWQBeZCTLBIlGqxNlkwScmly+N5JVXpIrDxGz4UAHwcwGRB5fgUAbQBdRT5icQgEHDgoFARBEDpkRh09Vm1dfQB6IvIIHBxyAAsUNQ0HVToISmQAdxQquAA3FBpBamQCvWV0zLBXdwwUIxzCgDozZpoIgAYoubdvZBKgkNlkQO9fAmJRrIpqOgZGQ3J1CEEYCa2DV+QAckdQ9+QAfmepshWJspnMLrR6EwgA)

This is called [Narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) and it's how you deal with figuring out which member of a union a value actually is.

Or in your case, perhaps something like:

```
data?.items?.map((node) => {
  return {
    id: node.id,
    type: TeaserType.Video,
    title: node.title,
    myDate:
      typeof node.myDate === 'string' ?
        node.myDate :
        node.myDate.timestamp,
  }
```